# Internationalize text in Qt Widgets

Tags: qt

In Qt, I'm aware of the tr() function that you can use to internationalize string literals in the code. But how does it work for text that I have entered in a widget's properties, such as `currentTabText` in the screenshot below? Do I have to set such properties in code too and use the tr() function or is there an easier way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing else is needed, Just make sure the attribute "translatable" is set to true(expand the currentTabText to see that)

By nothing else I mean nothing extra is needed apart from what is already being needed for tr() to work.
So I assume you already know about QTranslator , installTranslator(), lupdate and linguist etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the drop down list of `currentTabText`, and make sure that `translatable` checkbox is checked.